# Bootstrap Form Drop-down stops working when screen width reduced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

strange one here, I have a simple form using Bootstrap but when I reduce my browser width down to a mobile size (or even use a mobile itself) it stops working. I wish I could provide you with some code examples but I don't know where to start, it is pretty standard stuff.

Here is the example: https://www.safehandsplans.co.uk/funeral-plans/payment-options/calculator

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards
PB

Comment: we cannot help you without your code... please post the code of your form

Answer (score 0):

without examples it is not easy, I had that case once in the navbar and the problem was that after too much editing I had deleted a link in the header. 
make sure you have them all the cdn links:
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

FIXED! To cut a long story short it was a conflict in the structure, I had one col-xm-12 and a col-xs-12 which had a conflict of interest and was stopping it from working.